# how to register a function for a process to the shared memory touched by this process?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, multiprocess

I want to share information between multiple processes, I know if all the processes die and the shm_unlink is not called, the shared memory will still be there. I have to manually unmapped it and call shm_unlink.

But the thing is, sometimes it could throw exception and the processes terminated without calling shm_unlink. So I thought maybe I can register a function to the process, like on_exit. If this process is terminated unexpectly, this shared memory will still be released.

So can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know if all the processes die and the shm_unlink is not called, the shared memory will still be there.

No. Shared memory is in every process's memory space, just as ordinary virtual memory. When a process exits, all its virtual memory will be destroyed. When all participating processes exit, no shared memory will be there.

The only thing will remain if you forget to `shm_unlink()` is the file name created by `shm_open()`. Normally it's located at `/dev/shm`. But it's just a name of an empty file. So if you will run your program in a regular fashion, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thnx. I misunderstood the shared memory concept. I thought all the processes have the same virtual memory.